# Different model performance in MLP and CNN

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm experimenting with geometric shape classification. My datasets are 100x100 px thresholded black and white images of squares, circles and triangles in total 3000 and 1000 for each shape. They look like these:

[image] [image] [image]

But I got them as a csv file, where each row is the one dimensional representation of the image and last column is label.

I used MLP from sklearn to make a classifier. It performed well. Almost 99%.

```
df = pd.read_csv("img_data.csv", sep=";")
df = df.sample(frac=1)  # shuffling the whole dataset
X = df.drop('label', axis=1) # Because 'label' is the column of label  
y = df['label']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)

clf = MLPClassifier(solver='adam', activation="relu",alpha=1e-  5,hidden_layer_sizes=(1000,), random_state=1, verbose=True)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print('accuracy',accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Then I wanted to try with CNN. For that I used keras with tensorflow backend. But accuracy here couldn't cross above 92% even after 20 epochs. Here's my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("img_data.csv", sep=";")
df = df.sample(frac=1)  # shuffling the whole dataset
X = df.drop('label', axis=1) # Because 'label' is the column of label  
y = df['label']

X=X.as_matrix()
X = np.reshape(X, (-1, 100, 100, 1)) #made 1d to 2d

a = list(y)
label_binarizer = sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
label_binarizer.fit(range(max(a)))
y = label_binarizer.transform(a) # encoding one hot for labels
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(all_images, y, test_size=0.20)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=[100, 100, 1])) 
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 20
model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
      validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
      epochs=epochs, batch_size=64, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a very simple problem. There is very little structure inside the data, so I think you could try to reduce the depth of the neural network by removing the last two convolution and max pooling layers. Instead increase the number of nodes in the fully-connected layer, like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=[100, 100, 1])) 
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

You could also try to use some image augmentation techniques like shifting and rotating to increase your dataset. Then I expect the convnet to outperform the standard mlp.

Best

Comment: Thank for your answer. No improvement by trying your model architecture. I'll now try with image augmentation.